# React Router Dom link not working properly - page not showing

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm pretty new to React. Can someone shed a light into what am I doing wrong here? Link is not working (it points to /tutorials but nothing changes).

My app.js:

```
import "./App.css"
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { TutorialPage } from "./pages/Tutorial";
import { HomePage } from "./pages/Homepage";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <HomePage />
        <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        <Route exact path="/tutorials" component={TutorialPage} />
        </Routes>
    </>
  )
}
```

My Homepage file:

```
import React from "react";
import { Hero } from "../../components/Hero";
import "../../index.css"
import Features from "../../components/Features";

export function HomePage() {
  return (
    <>
    <Hero></Hero>
    <Features />
    </>
  );
}
```

And the Hero file, where **Navbar with link to /tutorials** is:

```
import React from "react";
import { Fragment } from 'react'
import { Popover, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import { MenuIcon, XIcon } from '@heroicons/react/outline'
import "../../index.css"
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const navigation = [
    { name: 'Features', href: '#features' },
    { name: 'Product', href: '#' },
    { name: 'Reviews', href: '#' },
    { name: 'Tutorials', href: '/tutorials' },
  ]
  
  export function Hero() {
    return (
      <div className="relative bg-white overflow-hidden">
        <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto">
          <div className="relative z-10 pb-8 bg-white sm:pb-16 md:pb-20 lg:max-w-2xl lg:w-full lg:pb-28 xl:pb-32">
            <svg
              className="hidden lg:block absolute right-0 inset-y-0 h-full w-48 text-white transform translate-x-1/2"
              fill="currentColor"
              viewBox="0 0 100 100"
              preserveAspectRatio="none"
              aria-hidden="true"
            >
              <polygon points="50,0 100,0 50,100 0,100" />
            </svg>
  
            <Popover>
              <div className="relative pt-8 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <nav className="relative flex items-center justify-between sm:h-10 lg:justify-start" aria-label="Global">
                  <div className="flex items-center flex-grow flex-shrink-0 lg:flex-grow-0">
                    <div className="flex items-center justify-between w-full md:w-auto">
                      <Link to="/">
                        <span className="sr-only">FlixVPN</span>
                        <img className="w-16 sm:h-16" src="/logo512.png" />
                      </Link>
                      <div className="-mr-2 flex items-center md:hidden">
                        <Popover.Button className="bg-white rounded-md p-2 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-flixblue-500">
                          <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
                          <MenuIcon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                        </Popover.Button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="hidden md:block md:ml-10 md:pr-4 md:space-x-8">
                    {navigation.map((item) => (
                      <Link
                        key={item.name}
                        to={item.href}
                        className="font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900"
                      >
                        {item.name}
                      </Link>
                    ))}
                    <a href="#" className="bg-flixblue-500 font-medium text-white p-3 rounded-md">
                      Get app
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </nav>
              </div>
  
              <Transition
                as={Fragment}
                enter="duration-150 ease-out"
                enterFrom="opacity-0 scale-95"
                enterTo="opacity-100 scale-100"
                leave="duration-100 ease-in"
                leaveFrom="opacity-100 scale-100"
                leaveTo="opacity-0 scale-95"
              >
                <Popover.Panel
                  focus
                  className="absolute z-10 top-0 inset-x-0 p-2 transition transform origin-top-right md:hidden"
                >
                  <div className="rounded-lg shadow-md bg-white ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 overflow-hidden">
                    <div className="px-5 pt-4 flex items-center justify-between">
                      <div>
                        <img
                          className="h-8 w-auto"
                          src="/logo512.png"
                          alt=""
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div className="-mr-2">
                        <Popover.Button className="bg-white rounded-md p-2 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-flixblue-500">
                          <span className="sr-only">Close main menu</span>
                          <XIcon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                        </Popover.Button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="px-2 pt-2 pb-3 space-y-1">
                    {navigation.map((item) => (
                      <Link
                      key={item.name}
                      to={item.href}
                      className="font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900"
                      >
                      {item.name}
                      </Link>
                  ))}
                    </div>
                    <a
                      href="#"
                      className="block w-full px-5 py-3 text-center font-medium text-flixblue-600 bg-flixblue-600 rounded-md hover:bg-gray-100"
                    >
                      Log in
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </Popover.Panel>
              </Transition>
            </Popover>
  
            <main className="mt-10 mx-auto max-w-7xl px-4 sm:mt-12 sm:px-6 md:mt-16 lg:mt-20 lg:px-8 xl:mt-28">
              <div className="sm:text-center lg:text-left">
                <h1 className="text-4xl tracking-tight font-extrabold text-gray-900 sm:text-5xl md:text-7xl">
                  <span className="block xl:inline">The only VPN you need to</span>{' '}
                  <span className="block text-flixblue-500 xl:inline">unblock Netflix</span>
                </h1>
                <p className="mt-3 text-base text-gray-500 sm:mt-5 sm:text-lg sm:max-w-xl sm:mx-auto md:mt-5 md:text-xl lg:mx-0">
                  High speed,  residential IP VPN that effectively <span className="font-semibold text-flixblue-500">unblocks Netflix, Hulu and other geo-restricted streaming services</span>. Unblock a library of more than 50,000 movies and TV shows you've never seen before.
                </p>
                <div className="mt-5 sm:mt-8 inline-flex">
                  <img
                  className="w-auto h-20"
                  src="/google-play-badge.png"
                  />
                  
                  <img
                  className="w-auto h-14 mt-3"
                  src="/download-app-store.svg"
                  />
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            </main>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="lg:absolute lg:inset-y-0 lg:right-0 lg:w-1/2">
          <img
            className="h-56 w-full object-cover sm:h-72 md:h-96 lg:w-full lg:h-full"
            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512070679279-8988d32161be?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=876&q=80"
            alt=""
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Page builds correctly everything works expect for the link. The /tutorials page is in place and only has a  which should show.

Also, my root index.js file:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; 
import './index.css'; 
import App from './App'; 
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals'; 
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";  

ReactDOM.render(   
<React.StrictMode>     
    <BrowserRouter>       
        <App />   
    </BrowserRouter>   
</React.StrictMode>,   

document.getElementById("root") );
```

Comment: Also, my root index.js file:

`import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
`

Comment: Are you using the version 5 or 6 for React Router Dom ?

Comment: @tomhikari React Router Dom 6.2.1